# Run selenium in the host with docker and Capybara

Tags: selenium, docker, capybara

I have tests with capybara in a docker container. I use this to setup selenium :

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  require 'selenium/webdriver'
  Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = ENV['FIREFOX_BINARY_PATH'] || Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

It work when we run tests with xvfb but I want to see the real browser when tests are running so I'm looking for a way to use the browser in the host.

I think it's possible to launch geckodriver on the host and share the port 4444 but I didn't succeeded yet. Capybara launch a new instance of geckodriver, on the container, each time.

What can I do?

### Edit 1 : Add more info

I all config I have for capybara :

```
#<Capybara::SessionConfig:0x0055ce67731a00
 @always_include_port=false,
 @app_host="http://domain-test.engagement.lvh.me:1300",
 @automatic_label_click=false,
 @automatic_reload=true,
 @default_host="http://www.example.com",
 @default_max_wait_time=5,
 @default_selector=:css,
 @enable_aria_label=false,
 @exact=false,
 @exact_text=false,
 @ignore_hidden_elements=true,
 @match=:smart,
 @raise_server_errors=true,
 @run_server=true,
 @save_path=#<Pathname:/app/tmp/capybara>,
 @server_errors=[StandardError],
 @server_host=nil,
 @server_port=1300,
 @visible_text_only=false,
 @wait_on_first_by_default=false>
```

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: rails s -b 0.0.0.0
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./tmp/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
    environment:
      - BUNDLE_JOBS=4
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - MEMCACHE_HOST=memcache
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
      - "1300:1300"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
      - memcache

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.9
    volumes:
      - ~/data/mongo/db:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis:2.8.17
    volumes:
      - ~/data/redis:/data

  memcache:
    image: memcached:1.5-alpine
```

And finally my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential qt5-default \
  libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x \
  xvfb rsync

ARG GECKODRIVER_VERSION=0.19.0
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz \
  && rm -rf /opt/geckodriver \
  && tar -C /opt -zxf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && rm /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && mv /opt/geckodriver /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION \
  && chmod 755 /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION \
  && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/geckodriver

RUN apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev \
  && wget --no-verbose https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-56.0.tar.bz2 \
  && tar -xjf firefox-56.0.tar.bz2 \
  && mv firefox /opt/firefox56 \
  && ln -s /opt/firefox56/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

ENV TZ Europe/Paris
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6 && \
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org

RUN gem install bundler

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: the simplest thing would be to install the browser inside a docker and run the test on it. You could also install vnc client which will help you debug the tests.

Comment: @GaurangShah VNC seems to be a little bit complicated for this simple thing. I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: [Selenium have pre built images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium), both standalone and hub versions. Then you get a port to connect to and don't have to bother with manage all the browser launching guff.

Comment: @Matt it seems I have the same problem I explained in the answer of Thomas Walpole. I have "Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page." on each pae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get Selenium to use a remote geckodriver instance you need to provide the `url` option to it.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  require 'selenium/webdriver'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, url: 'http://<your ip as reachable from docker>:<port geckodriver is available on>')
end
```

This will then require you to run geckodriver on the machine your want firefox to run on, possibly using the `--binary` option to specify where firefox is located. It will also probably require setting `Capybara.app_host` (and possibly `Capybara.always_include_port` depending on your exact configuration) so the browser requests are routed back to the app under test running on the docker instance.

Another thing to consider is that the AUT will need to be bound to an interface on the docker instance which is reachable from the host.  By default Capybara binds to the 127.0.0.1 interface which probably isn't reachable, so you can set `Capybara.server = '0.0.0.0'` to bind to all available interfaces, or specify the specific external interface.

Comment: It's better but I have an "Unable to connect" error when firefox starts. The current url is http://domain-test.lvh.me:1300/ . When I try to do a telnet, it is not a able to connect to the port 1300. I can't connect with telnet on the container even when the test is run locally and the test pass. The domain used works. I still have to run the test with xvbf. Any clue?

Comment: @Dougui Since `*.lvh.me` subdomains resolve to `127.0.0.1` that's not correct for a browser running on your host to connect to the docker instance - You need to set `Capybara.host` to the url that is your docker instance from your host.  Additionally you may need to set `Capybara.server_host`, and possibly `Capybara.server_port`, which sets where the app server gets bound to. The default server_host of `127.0.0.1` on your docker instance is probably not reachable from your host, so you need to set `server_host` to whichever interface of the docker instance is reachable from your host.

Comment: @Dougi - whoops that should have said "You need to set `Capybara.app_host` to the url that is your docker instance from your host"

Comment: Ok but with docker we use kind of port forwarding so the host I use is localhost with the port 1300 and it forwards requests to the app in the container. It works for 'normal' apps.

Comment: @Dougui So if do actually have port forwarding from you localhost to your docker instance, then if you open a browser manually on your host and go to `http://localhost:1300` while tests are running, do you see anything? Also where is the 1300 coming from?  How does your setup know what port to forward that to on the docker instance? Have you set `Capybara.server_port` to a fixed value?  Maybe you should post your docker network config.

Comment: When I go on localhost:3000 I have the error described in my first comment. The port is set with Capybara.server_port. I use the --port option of docker to forward ports.

Comment: @Dougui Huh??? what does 3000 have to do with anything? You said 1300 before --  What exactly are your Capybara settings (since this is the first time you've actually mentioned using `server_port`)?  What options exactly are you passing to docker?

Comment: @Dougui I think the issue is that Capybara is binding to 127.0.0.1 on the docker instance which isn't the interface whose port is actually forwarded to from the host,  try setting `Capybara.server_host = "0.0.0.0"` or `Capybara.server_host = "web"`.  I'm also confused as to why you have `command: rails s -b 0.0.0.0` if you're running Capybara in the docker instance since Capybara starts the app itself.

Comment: It works with capybara serve on "0.0.0.0". Thanks a lot ! Please, edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Dougui - Updated